# DRF non-model serializer for POST method to upload some data

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I want to create an endpoint in my API that can be used to upload data that need to be parsed. The parsed results will be stored in the DB, but the data is not related to DB models format.
My plan was to use the generic Serializer class and then get the different values directly from the input.
My JSON body for the POST call  would look like this:

```
{
  id : int
  config : string
  hash : string
}
```

My serializer would look like this:

```
class MyConfigUploadSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    id = serializers.Integerfield(required=True)
    config = serializers.Charfield(required=True, allow_null=False)
    hash = serializers.Charfield(required=True, allow_null=False)
```

Basically I want to call my own function from that serializer. Something like this:

```
parse_data(id, config, hash)
```

Now I am not sure if I should rather should try to use the create() or the to_internal_value() function to call my function to parse the code and that will store the parsed at a in the DB.

I would also like to use the validation function to make sure there is an object with the ID in the DB and the format of the rest of the data is correct.

Comment: Hey there, could you do your question? Because it isn't explicit.

Comment: Hi, I am looking for the best method to archive what I want to do. if it is better to use the create() or the to_internal_value()  to call my function, or do it in a completely different way.

Answer (score 0):

For that operation, you can override the `.to_internal_value(self, data)` function.

As described on DRF docs: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#overriding-serialization-and-deserialization-behavior.

> `.to_internal_value` takes the unvalidated incoming data as input and should return the validated data that will be made available as serializer.validated_data. The return value will also be passed to the .create() or .update() methods if .save() is called on the serializer class.

Comment: I am looking for an example to use the .to_internal_value(self, data) function. I have not found anything so far.